# bootstrap: подключение к react проекту

Tags: css, bootstrap, reactjs, npm, импорт

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно корректно подключить bootstrap библиотеку к react проекту?

установил bootstrap глобально на свой ПК:

```
npm install bootstrap -g
```

после чего он у меня появился в папке

```
c:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bootstrap\
```

Все замечательно, но как мне получить доступ к css файлам из моего react проекта?

Я понимаю, что можно поставить прямую ссылку, но мне кажется это неправильно

В `package.json` я библиотеку прописал

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "bootstrap":"4.3.1"
  },
```

Есть ли возможность в проекте делать как-то так:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

?

Comment: есть хорошая библиотека https://reactstrap.github.io/ попробуйте - уверен что понравится:)

Comment: она так же даёт сетки и всё такое? потому что мне это в большей части нужно, сами стили в своем проекте я буду значительно переделывать

Comment: вы про это?:) https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить бутстрап пакет `npm i bootstrap`, а затем можно импортировать стили в компонент с помощью строчки `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` (обычно вызывают один раз в корневом `index.js`.

Comment: Спасибо. Но, как я понял, библиотека была установлена локально, а если у меня таких проектов сотня - никакого же диска не напасешься и при установке глобально `-g` библиотека ставится так, что к ней косвенный доступ (не по прямой ссылке) и не удавалось получить :(

Comment: @Zhihar Вы правы. Но есть нюанс в том, что другие пользователи, пытаясь развернуть приложение, могут столкнуться с проблемой отсутсвтующих зависимостей.